# VLC command line batch file to rip audio CD

Tags: vlc

Anyone have a batch file to rip a CD using VLC player, so I don't have to rip one track at a time using the GUI?

Comment: This should be on superuser.com

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just replace the ***D:*** with your CD drive (2 ***bold italic*** occurrences):

```
@ECHO OFF

    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    SET /a x=0

    FOR /R D:\ %%G IN (*.cda) DO (CALL :SUB_VLC "%%G")
    GOTO :eof

    :SUB_VLC
    call SET /a x=x+1

    ECHO Transcoding %1
    REM Here's where the actual transcoding/conversion happens. The next line
    REM fires off a command to VLC.exe with the relevant arguments:
    CALL "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc" -I http cdda:///D:/ --cdda-track=!x! :sout=#transcode{vcodec=none,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access="file",mux=raw,dst="Track!x!.mp3"} --noloop vlc://quit

    :eof
```

Comment: If you have a 64bit Windows, change the CALL path of VLC to: "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc"

Comment: There is 64 bit VLC for 64 bit Windows

Comment: This is awesome. Figure out how to get album info automatically added as well and this will be the perfect batch!

Comment: @ringstaff 
VLC uses an external server (CDDB) to retrieve information for Audio CDs, but it doesn't do this for MP3s but trust their tags embedded in the file. This tool may be used to update MP3 Tags with info from CDDB, http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Other-AUDIO-Tools/CDDB-MP3-Tool.shtml

Comment: This just gives me a bunch of 0-byte MP3 files.

Comment: In Windows 10, this fails if their is a space in the filename, like the "Program Files" part of the directory path. 

So, you need to move VLC to something like "C:\VLC" and modify the path in the script for Windows 10.

Comment: I reduced the #transcode section to just {acodec=mp3} to avoid producing 0-byte files.

Comment: I noticed the 0-byte file thing happens if you have VLC set to "loop" playback, as this is a persistent setting on the player. Reducing the transcode section is not the answer, I added `--noloop` to the command, and it worked for me.